# Windows 10 iot, Raspberry Pi 2, DHT22/AM2302 Sensor Not Receiving Data

Tags: windows-iot, dht22

Currently I am using the DHT22/AM2302 which has a built in 5.1k resistor, using the program provided from https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/GpioOneWire.htm and connected the sensors VCC to 3.3V(Pin1), GND to GND(Pin6), and DOUT to GPIO4(Pin7). Everything seems to be hooked up right but when running the program no sensor is detected. Has anyone had a similar situation?

Comment: The example may be incomplete... *sigh* at Microsoft, very common. I think you may be missing a permission in the `app.xaml` - Did you add `xmlns:local="using:GpioOneWire"`  - Try this code as is - https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/GpioOneWire

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try and report back tonight!  But quick question could there be something wrong with the sensor?

Comment: Its difficult to say if the sensor is faulty.. you would need to test it on another platform maybe, like Arduino or something. Or using Raspbian SD card for test.

Comment: To report back, I have tested the sensor using Linux Raspbian-jessie.  So good news the senor nor the pi is broken, bad news is the pain in the butt windows 10 iot will be trying to solve the software issue.  Followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHTnU1T8ETk for the linux setup.  Now on to windows 10 thanks ppumkin I'll give it a shot!

Comment: NO problem. It must be something or nothing. Software blindness causing you to overlook a simple issue, a line of code, a boolean, something daft. OneWire is a standard protocol so there is no compatibility issues here but may just be software related. Keep on hacking.. IoT is maturing by the month, more things available, better things coming. When you do solve the issue, please post an answer here. It may be helpful to somebody.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Sad to say, but, no I am still working on a solution.  The program GPIOOneWire is whats giving me the trouble.  I've tried what you suggested but found after redownloading the code that it was already fixed.  However a update for visual studio was issued today.  Along with some added software that was recommended from visual studio(something Tools) after open the new GPIOOneWire program.(have no idea why it just now told me to install said software but hopefully it will resolve the issue)Currently updating visual studio as I type this.

Comment: This is what I have concluded so far.  I do not have a hardware issue, and I know this because the sensor was tested using Linux and it worked fine.  It is also a fact that windows 10 iot is not a real time OS therefore it makes difficult to capture the sensors data. Reading these other forums:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5edd0f6-8a97-4578-a943-e4fb2b756931/bitbanging-onewire-and-asyncawait-framework-focus?forum=WindowsIoT https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d2a9a5a-64fb-4c5b-af64-844e5831379d/help-for-dht11-humiture-sample?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: Others have had similar issues. But they have had slightly different circuits than I. Which leads me to believe that my sensor's model(which has a 5.1k resistor) doesn't fit the programs timer. In other words the level of resistance affects the out put of the sensor.  Source:http://expediteapps.com/blog/temperature-with-gpios-in-windows10iot-with-rpi2/

Comment: Raspbian isn't Realtime OS either. But that doesn't matter, because SPI runs on its own dedicated clock, independent from OS. So does the UART and I2C. They have their own limitations in speed and accuracy, but will always buffer data properly. I suspect the IoT driver has a problem. Best thing would be to search the GitHub Issues and see if anybody reported this, if not, please create a new issue, your hardware, steps you have taken. I cant see it being OS or Hardware, it must be the middleware. Your research may help allot of other people later.

Comment: Thank you for all your help ppumkin, and yes I'll make sure to document in detail and post a solution once one is found.  The GitHub issue as been opened just have to wait for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't say I don't learn anything, and this experience, even though it was very frustrating especially since I am very new to Windows 10 iot, was eye opening.  My issue has been resolved.

If you have a DHT22/AM2302 and you are experiencing issue with getting no feedback from your temperature sensor then check with these troubleshooting tips.

**Do you have a hardware issue?** Check both the sensor and raspberry pi for damage or defects. Do a test run of the sensor on a different OS such as Linux.

**Is your circuit correctly connected to the raspberry pi?** Make sure all pins are connected to their correct corresponding GPIO pins and a resistor was added(other have stated a resistor is not necessary but if you're having issues it wont hurt to try) I had used 5.1K resistor.  Is your windows 10 iot up to date?

**Is your OS up-to-date?**
This is a big one mainly because it was why my sensor wasn't working with the GPIOOneWire program. **This is a quote from jordanrh1 who is one of the developers of the GPIOOneWire program"The DHT11 sample only works on build 10556 and higher."** I was using Version 10.0.10240 thinking since I had just reinstalled windows 10 iot it was up to date. So always check your iot versions as a troubleshooting tip**

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.